# Micronaut - Get Running environment name in the view

Tags: thymeleaf, micronaut

I have a small Micronaut application with a view layer (thymeleaf). Now I want to integrate Google Analytics or some other tracking tool. Of course this should be just loaded in production mode but how can I do a check for the environment in the view layer?

I start the application in the following way:

java -Dmicronaut.environments=prod -jar mywebsite.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject the `io.micronaut.context.env.Environment` and pass the result of `getActiveNames()` as part of your view model

EDIT:

If you want to add this data to each model without touching each controller method you can add a server filter that happens before the view filter to manipulate the response, or create a piece of around advice that can manipulate the return value of the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about this too but I don't wanna touch each controller method. Can I somehow get the environment to the LayoutFile?

Comment: I could not find another way, so I did as you suggested!

Comment: @James Can we use something like ControllerAdvice to configure global variable in thymeleaf  for micronaut? I see in spring boot we simple need to use enviroment in thymeleaf.

Comment: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-views/latest/api/io/micronaut/views/model/ViewModelProcessor.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solving this problem is to utilise @Replaces annotation to override ThymeleafViewsRenderer class and add common data in your class.

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Replaces
import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment
import io.micronaut.core.beans.BeanMap
import io.micronaut.core.io.Writable
import io.micronaut.core.io.scan.ClassPathResourceLoader
import io.micronaut.core.util.ArgumentUtils
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.views.exceptions.ViewRenderingException
import io.micronaut.views.thymeleaf.ThymeleafViewsRenderer
import io.micronaut.views.thymeleaf.WebContext
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context
import org.thymeleaf.context.IContext
import org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateEngineException
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver

import javax.annotation.Nonnull
import javax.annotation.Nullable
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Replaces(bean = ThymeleafViewsRenderer.class)
class CustomThymeleafFilter extends ThymeleafViewsRenderer {

    CustomThymeleafFilter(AbstractConfigurableTemplateResolver templateResolver, TemplateEngine templateEngine, ClassPathResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        super(templateResolver, templateEngine, resourceLoader)
    }

    @Inject
    Environment environment

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public Writable render(@Nonnull String viewName, @Nullable Object data) {
        ArgumentUtils.requireNonNull("viewName", viewName);
        return (writer) -> {
            
            //following block adds environments variable to model
            Map dataMap = variables(data)
            dataMap.put("environment", environment.activeNames)
            
            IContext context = new Context(Locale.US, dataMap);
            processView(viewName, writer, context);
        };
    }

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public Writable render(@Nonnull String viewName, @Nullable Object data,
                           @Nonnull HttpRequest<?> request) {
        ArgumentUtils.requireNonNull("viewName", viewName);
        ArgumentUtils.requireNonNull("request", request);
        return (writer) -> {

            //following block adds environments variable to model
            Map dataMap = variables(data)
            dataMap.put("environment", environment.activeNames)
            
            IContext context = new WebContext(request, Locale.US, dataMap);
            processView(viewName, writer, context);
        };
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> variables(@Nullable Object data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
        if (data instanceof Map) {
            return (Map<String, Object>) data;
        } else {
            return BeanMap.of(data);
        }
    }

    private void processView(String viewName, Writer writer, IContext context) {
        try {
            engine.process(viewName, context, writer);
        } catch (TemplateEngineException e) {
            throw new ViewRenderingException("Error rendering Thymeleaf view [" + viewName + "]: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```